# Javascript: Uncaught ReferenceError

Tags: javascript, html

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"/>
<script type="text/javascript">
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#name').val('Name1');
 });
 function clickMe(){
  console.log('click me called');
 }
</script>
</head>
<body>
    Person Name: <input type="text" id="name" data-bind="value:personName">
    <input type="submit" value="Save" onClick="javascript:clickMe()"/>
</body>

</html>
```

In the code above neither the function inside document.ready is getting executed nor "clickMe" function is getting executed when "Save" button is clicked.

When I click on "Save" button, Uncaught ReferenceError: clickMe is not defined error message is seen.

Comment: To what is the error pointing?

Comment: The `<script />` element is not a self-closing element. It has to be `<script></script>` (hence the "strange" syntax highlighting)

Comment: Do you have other JavaScript libraries loading in the page? (Does jQuery have the dollar alias?)

Comment: @Andreas Thanks a lot. The change suggested fixed the error.

Comment: You're welcome but please accept one of the answers below for the sake of completeness :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you haven't closed `script` tag of `jQuery`. `<script>` is not self-closing tag.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery- 1.11.3.js"/>
```

Should be

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
```

Code:

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#name').val('Name1');
    });

    function clickMe() {
      alert('click me called');
    }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  Person Name:
  <input type="text" id="name" data-bind="value:personName">
  <input type="submit" value="Save" onClick="javascript:clickMe()" />
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Scripts can not be self closing. You need to have the closing `</script>` tag on the jQuery include.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"/>
```

needs to be

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to refer to script like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js"></script>
```